# Need to load specific .amount class using jquery with .load() on a timed interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several elements on the page with the `.amount` class. How do I load a specific one?

This is the script I'm using...

```
<script>
  $(function () {
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
     setInterval(function () { 
         $('.amount').load('//example.com/ex/ex/ .amount'); 
     }, 15000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You need some way to uniquely identify the element you want to load so I would add an `id` attribute to it and change your jquery selector.

Comment: is it not possible to use something like #div.a.span.amount ? Ive not had any luck

Comment: i think the way you are using load, its not possible in terms of full url the way you written it.

Comment: I would rather not load the full url...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of it but you can give it a shot:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
     var i = 0;
     setInterval(function () { 
         $('.amount').load('//example.com/ex/ex/ .amount:eq('+i+')');
         i++; 
     }, 15000);
  });
</script>
```

---

I like if you try to use it without full url may be something like:

```
$('.amount').load('/ex/ex/ .amount:eq('+i+')');
```

---

### Note:

Also i thought that using `setInterval` is not a good idea because it will run forever at the intervals of `15000` ms.